# s:form tag action parameters being removed

Tags: java, forms, jsp, parameters, struts2

I have searched and searched and this is destroying me. I have this:

```
<s:form method="post" action="%{methodOne}" cssClass="buttons">
```

The emailFormUrl returns the URL correctly but the parameters have been stripped.

```
  public String methodOne() {
    return anotherClass.methodTwo(id);
  }
```

Which speaks of:

```
  public static String methodTwo(
      String id) {
    return fastEncode("", "longurl/view.jsp",
        new ParameterPairing("id", id));
  }
```

For some reason, the id is being stripped, this leaves me with a validation error and doesn't complete the action that I require. As I am aware we did not have a problem with it before the July urgent security update but it is small functionality that is rarely used (an argument for its removal I guess).

I don't want to add a hidden parameter as I want to understand the reason that this is not working, not a workaround (I am still in the heavy learning part of my career).

Comment: If you are making a post request why do you need that parameters in the url?

Comment: In short, I do not know, this is my first couple of months using struts after university (University: a place that leaves you thinking you know everything until employment where you learn you have a similar quantity of knowledge as a peacock). Essentially, I am setting up the url that has the parameter of the instance id appended. The form sends the information and instructs an email to be sent containing information that is calculated based on this instance id. I have tested all other uses of this action="%{method" and they seem to be responding fine. I wanted to add the <hidden param> which

Comment: of course fixes it but because it used to work I need to find out what is wrong and what has changed. My understanding does not cover enough breadth to know why we are trying to complete the action using this method. I am sorry that I cannot provide more information - we were all learning once though hey?

Comment: 1) Enable devMode and check carefully all the output during the call; 2) put a `log.debug(id)` as first row of both methodOne and methodTwo, to ensure it is stripped; 3) Where id comes from ? where is it initialized ? Post more code if possible.

Comment: Sorry that I disappeared - thought it would be fun to break a limb so had a few cheeky days off, and thank you for the response and feedback.. I will have a good read this afternoon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In servlet environment the `<s:form>` tag uses `ServletUrlRenderer` class to render form url.
If configuration for the action specified in `action` attribute cannot be found then literal value (w/o parameters) of an `action` attribute will be used.

**Note:** you need to use action name w/o extension in order that it can be found in configuration. So `some_action?foo=bar` will be set with parameters in form if you have `some_action` in configuration, but `some_action.action?foo=bar` won't be found because of `.action` extension and parameters will be stripped.

Comment: As per comment above, sorry that I disappeared, had some skeletal issues, turns out that stairs are not my friend. I will have a read through and play again this afternoon. I don't understand Romans comment though.