# Why is my param value missing in generated URL?

Tags: java, url, struts2, param

Here is my code:

```
<s:iterator value="ChapterTreeList" id="chapterTree">
  ...
    <s:url 
        id="deployChaptersUrl"
        action="ajaxDeployChapter"
        includeContext="false">
      <s:param 
               name="nodeId"
               value="%{#chapterTree.nodeId}"/>
    </s:url>

    <s:form
         id="deployChapters%{#chapterTree.nodeId}" 
         action="%{deployChapterUrl}"
         theme="simple"
         method="POST">
    </s:form>

    ...
</s:iterator>
```

I expect multiple forms like this one below:

```
<form 
     id="deployChapters27623"
     name="deployChapters27623"
     action="/path/to/ajaxDeployChapter.action?nodeId=27623" <-- nodeId here
     method="POST">
</form>
```

But instead I get forms like this:

```
<form 
     id="deployChapters27623"
     name="deployChapters27623"
     action="/path/to/ajaxDeployChapter.action" <-- nodeId is missing here
     method="POST">
</form>
```

**Struts 2.3.15.1**

Comment: Use hidden fields for forms instead of url with params.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21478791/1700321.

Comment: Also use `var` instead of `id` (deprecated) on Iterators, and migrate ASAP to *at least* 2.3.15.3, or better to 2.3.16.1, because from 2.0.0 to 2.3.15.2, Struts version are affected by security issues discovered recently.

Comment: Use `<s:hidden>` tag for hidden fields.

Comment: @AleksandrM I have found the root cause... it's not Struts ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved my issue:

```
<s:form
     id="deployChapters%{#chapterTree.nodeId}" 
     action="%{deployChapterUrl}"
     theme="simple"
     method="POST">
     <s:hidden name="nodeId" value"%{#chapterTree.nodeId}" />
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 2):

`POST` HTTP method sends parameters into the request body. This is the difference between `POST` and `GET` that supports parameters into the query string.

So, you just should not even try to send query string as a part of POST. It will not work anyway. If you need to send `nodeId` you have 2 options;

1. send it as a URL path: `/path/to/ajaxDeployChapter.action/27623`.
2. create hidden form field `nodeId` and populate its value.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used Struts before, however I will hazard a guess.

```
<s:form
     id="deployChapters%{#chapterTree.nodeId}" 
     action="%{deployChapterUrl}"
     theme="simple"
     method="POST">
</s:form>
```

Should it be this?

```
<s:form
     id="deployChapters%{#chapterTree.nodeId}" 
     action="%{deployChapterUrl}?%{#chapterTree.nodeId}"
     theme="simple"
     method="POST">
</s:form>
```